# Запретить движение элемента при достижении препятсвия

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это `draggable` элементы.
Задача 1: запретить движение элемента при достижении препятствия в виде аналогичного элемента.

Задача 2: при достижении курсором середины припятствия елемент должен перепрыгнуть за припятсвие, если достаточно места (исходя из размера перетаскиваемого элемента). Нашел в документации по Jquery события `drag` возможность `Constrain movement via ui.position:`, но не пойму как его применить в моей ситуации.

Код `draggable`:

```
function drag() {
    $('.sossage')
        .draggable({
            axis: 'x',
            containment: 'parent',
            disabled: disable,
            start: function () {
                $('.pl-popup').hide();
                $(this).css({
                    'z-index': 1
                })
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).css({
                    'z-index': 0
                });
            }
        })
        .droppable({
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                console.log(ui.position);
            }
        })
}
```

Так же эти элементы ресайзятся. При ресайзинге нужно запретить растягивание элемента при достижении препятствия аналогично. Так же растягивание не должно продолдаться при достижении краев родительского элемента. Код ресайзинга так же прилагаю:

```
 $('.sossage')
        .mousedown(function (e) {
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resize_target = e.target;
                resizeStateRight = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
                disable = true;
                drag();
            }
            if (e.offsetX >= 0 && e.offsetX <= 5) {
                resize_target = e.target;
                resizeStateLeft = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
                disable = true;
                drag();
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeStateRight = false;
            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeStateRight = false;
                resize_target = null;
                disable = false;
                drag();
            }
            if (e.offsetX >= 0 && e.offsetX <= 5) {
                resizeStateLeft = false;
                resize_target = null;
                disable = false;
                drag();
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            var widthOffset;
            if (resizeStateRight == true) {
                widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $(resize_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
                $('.pl-popup').hide();
            }
            if (resizeStateLeft == true) {
                widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;
                $(resize_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth + widthOffset) + 'px',
                    'left': (initialLeft - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });
                $('.pl-popup').hide();
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeStateRight = false;
            resizeStateLeft = false;
            disable = false;
            drag();
        });
```

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается сделать?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Описанные задачи не получается сделать. Не могу нарыть как отслеживать позиции елементов относительно друг друга при перекрытии одним другого.

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы пользователи ru.SO сделали ваши задачи за вас?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, чтобы сделали - не хочу. Хочу чтобы дали направление и подсказали как это реализовать. Потому, что я даже примерно не понимаю куда копать. Для этого я и дал подробное описание задач.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить событие [drag( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) в котором отслеживать текущие координаты и сравнивать их с другими элементами и принимать соответствующие действия. Как проверять пересечения с другими объектами думаю понятно?

Для проверки вам надо сделать выборку этих элементов или через $(".elem-class") например или отдельно как то хранить это в переменной javascript.
Потом идёт школьная программа - как проверить пересечение отрезков - это я думаю тривиально?

Comment: как раз как проверять пересечение с другими элементами потятно меньше всего) Если вы можете дать малюсенький пример - это будет чудесно. Отслеживание текущего - понятно, а взаимодействие с другими - нет.

Comment: @Baga а скажите что именно не понятно в этом процессе проверки? Как получить эти элементы, как проверить пересечение, что-то другое?

Comment: Чад, полагаю самое не понятно проверка пересечения. Дело в том что все элементы разной длины могут быть и их может быть разное колчичество. И правый конец двигаемого елемента должен как-то сопоставляться с левым краем препятсвия, а в нашем распоряжении только `left` значение

Comment: Нашел в документации `Constrain movement via ui.position:` но не пойму как его применить к моей ситуации